# Cache Policies:Write-back on miss of exclusive cache( multi-level cache)

Tags: caching

I have a bit of confusion regarding the cache policies.
I have some basic understanding which is not sufficient.

For the write-back with write-allocate(WBWA):

1.When a write/read miss, if it is a dirty block, we first send(write) it to lower level. With write allocate, we go to next level cache to look for that block and fetch it back and write to current level again. So a write miss followed by a write hit. The question is, for an exclusive cache, if we find the missed block in a lower level cache and bring it back and write again to the current level, we are having two copies in both level which is contradictory to exclusive policy. Do we need to invalidate that block in lower level cache to make sure there is only one copy exists?

Answer (score 0):

We always know that top level entry is the correct one so invalidating lower ones would be redundant